# About cluster variables obtained by (sequentially) mutating at exchangeable variables from an initial cluster

Tags: rt.representation-theory, ac.commutative-algebra, cluster-algebras

Let $\Sigma=(X,ex,B)$ be a seed, $\mathcal{A}(\Sigma)$ a corresponding geometric cluster algebra and $\mathcal{X}_{\Sigma}$ the set of all cluster variables of $\mathcal{A}(\Sigma)$. We call a sequence $m=(x_1,\dots,x_k)$, $k \geq 1$, consisting of distinct exchangeable variables from $ex$ a *simple sequence* and let $\mu_m:=\mu_{x_k} \circ \cdots \circ \mu_{x_1}$. Is the equality
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{X}_{\Sigma}=\{y \in \mathcal{X}_{\Sigma}|\mu_m(x)=y \;\text{for some simple sequence}\; m \;\text{and some} \; x \in ex\}
\end{equation}
true in general? The $\supseteq$ part is trivial, but the other way around confuses me. So for instance, for a type $A$ cluster algebra this should be true, but I am not sure about other types. Any help in a form of a hint/explanation/reference/counter example would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you asking if we get every cluster variable by mutating at most once at each vertex? That doesn't seem possibly true: there are usually infinitely many cluster variables. Maybe I'm confused about what you are asking though...

Comment: Hi @SamHopkins, thanks for the comment. I am asking if we can get every cluster variable by mutating  at variables from the initial seed only. So say if $ex=\{x_1,\dots,x_k\}$ then, for instance, we can do $\mu_{x_k}\circ \cdots \circ \mu_{x_1}$ or just $\mu_{x_1} \circ \mu_{x_2}$, etc . Yeah, that's too much to ask, as you pointed out. Maybe it is true for finite type guys.

Comment: The usual definition of a cluster variable is something obtained under iterated mutation (by arbitrarily long but finite sequences of mutations) from the initial seed, so your equality is necessarily true by that definition.  There are other characterisations in certain situations (and in particular some things to think/worry about in the infinite rank case) so if your definition of cluster variable isn't this, it would be helpful to know what you are using.

Comment: Hi @JanGrabowski, thank you for your comment.  Seems like I am failing in explaining myself properly.  Say we have an initial seed arising from a triangulation (of a marked surface). I can flip a diagonal $a$ to get a diagonal $c$, say, then flip some diagonal $b$. Then I could flip $c$, but I don't want to allow for that as $c$ wasn't in the initial cluster.  On the other hand, flipping $a$ then $b$ is fine. Does that make more sense?

Comment: As I said before, there are clearly only finitely many sequences of the kind you have in mind, which means for infinite type cluster algebras there's no chance of reaching every cluster variable. But even for *finite type* (like Type A which you mentioned), I don't think you'll be able to get to every cluster variable in that few mutations. Indeed the diameter of the associahedron apparently grows like $2n$ (see https://arxiv.org/abs/1207.6296), which is more than the number of flips you're allowing.

Comment: Thanks for explaining @amator2357; because you'd not named the variables in your fixed ex, I misunderstood. I agree with @SamHopkins: this will almost never happen. In particular if you can find a cluster with no variables from ex such that no mutations of any of these are in ex. If you're working on surfaces, this might not be too hard, since you just have to construct a triangulation that looks "transverse" to your initial one (i.e. has its edges as different as possible). For general CAs, I'd conjecture your equality only holds for a small number of cases in very small rank.

Comment: Thank you both for your comments, you have been very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Not really an answer, but a comment about the related question:

> Can one reach every cluster in that way ?

It is rather easy to check (using [sagemath](https://www.sagemath.org/) or [Keller's applet](https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/%7Ebernhard.keller/quivermutation/)) that for the cyclic quiver in type $D_n$, not every cluster can be reached in that way. For example, only 13 among the 14 clusters in type $D_3$ are reached.

A conjecture for the number of reached clusters for this initial quiver in type $D_n$ can be found in this [OEIS sequence](https://oeis.org/A165205).

**EDIT:**

Even in type $A_4$, not all clusters are reached if the initial cluster is not the equioriented Dynkin quiver.

Here is a small sage program that generates the set of reached clusters:

```
def recursive_comb(carquois):
    """
    EXAMPLES::

        sage: Q = ClusterQuiver(DiGraph({0:[1]}))
        sage: len(list(recursive_comb(Q)))
        5
    """
    n = carquois.n()
    seed = ClusterSeed(carquois)
    initial_cluster = seed.cluster()

    def voisins(s):
        c = s.cluster()
        for i in range(n):
            if c[i] in initial_cluster:
                yield s.mutate(i, inplace=False)

    return RecursivelyEnumeratedSet([seed], voisins, structure='graded')
```

**EDIT:**

Using the same program, one can see that some cluster variables are missing already for some choices of initial quiver in type $D_4$:

```
sage: Q1 = ClusterQuiver(DiGraph({'b':['c'],'c':['d','e']}))
sage: Q2 = ClusterQuiver(DiGraph({'c':['b','d','e']}))
sage: len(set(v for c in recursive_comb(Q1) for v in c.cluster()))
16
sage: len(set(v for c in recursive_comb(Q2) for v in c.cluster()))
15
```

**EDIT**:

Even in type $A$, some clusters can be out of reach:

```
sage: Q1 = ClusterQuiver(DiGraph({'b':['c','a'],'c':['d']}))
sage: len(list(recursive_comb(Q1)))
37
```

instead of 42, the full number of clusters.

Comment: Very interesting, thank you for sharing! I'd imagine that you could reach every cluster in that way when working with type $A_n$ guys. Do you know if it's true?

Comment: Great to know this, thank you for that insight!